# Master + Slave database architecture vs. Master + Memcache

Tags: database, architecture, memcached, scalability

Let’s assume we have one server with a database and N servers that can be used for caching data with Memcache. Every record in database can have several (but substantially less than N) representations in a cache. For example, entity with id 108 can be cached by keys entity_108_1, entity_108_2, ..., entity_108_10. When some record in a database changes, the respective records in cache are being replaced with a new data.

Why is this architecture not better than master/slave database set-up? It seems like it has same advantages while additionally not suffering from replication lags.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is better to go with memcache. Not just lags during replication make problems, but your N servers don't need huge HDD space (if we assume that you have huge database). On the other hand, you will not achieve redundancy. If your master database server dies, you will not have anyone to take it's place. So, slave servers are necessary for those purposes, but most likely you don't need N of them, and if you can achieve scalability by using memcache, there is no reason not to do so (I mean, if you have developed applications that know how to use it). From my experience, it is always easier to maintain memcached instance than a slave MySQL server (and is probably the same with other database engines).

Of course, all of this makes sense if you developed applications that know how to use memcache. It is always easier just to add one more connection string into your config and to use it for read-only purposes from some database server in the same way you use it with master. Using data from some other data source (like memcache) assumes that you buld your application in that way.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you will still have a master/slave setting for db even if you have N nodes for memcache

solution comes with cons and pros

this is not better than master/slave if we are talking in a write heavy scenario.

the write process would need to expire all cached objects across all memcache nodes and have to wait for the "successful" responses since you want to avoid access to any copy of the old data. in this case, depending on numbers of cached object copies and network speed, you might suffer from poor performance. that said, since you dont know which node has a copy, you are going to have to send the expire request to all nodes...... :(